# Associating data with a many-to-many association

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have an entity `Person` with property `employers` which is collection (and other profile information such as full name). Also I have an entity `Employers` with property `employers` which is collection too (and also some general information such as name). It is a many-to-many bidirectional association (I want both to get employers associated with a person and employees associated with the employer). Now I want to associate some data with a mapping (e.g. job position or when the person was hired).

The original idea was to create a class which extends `Employer` and adds required properties. But this is not possible because it is a bidirectional association.

Other idea is to create a new Entity which has references to `Person`, `Employer` and required properties (e.g. job position). I can't see any disadvantages at the moment in this solution.

Is there a better way to do it (in other words, are there potential disadvantage that I missed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This many to many example is almost textbook. You should almost certainly decompose into two one-to-many relationships pointing towards a "link table". The disadvantage is the extra join, however most designs will utilise this pattern in an OLTP database.